# lib CURL is not honoring TIMEOUT as it shows document not exist

Tags: php, c++, curl, elasticsearch, libcurl

I have strange problem as I have high speed transaction application(written in C++ )  which will complete entire transaction with in second (Best case is with in ms) . 
My Application is writing document to Elastic search server and after successful writing , immediately application trying to access that document .
But Elastic Search server is returning as "Document doesn't exist".
Eventually Application fails.

I tried with TIMEOUT in CURl options(upto 100S ) , but it's not solving the case.
And after magic happened with sleep(1s)i.e. with sleep of 1 second after document written into elastic search server , Elastic search server returning as "Document Exist".

Can somebody help me understand the issue and proper solution as putting sleep is not good programming practice !!!

Comment: curl's timeout is a *maximum* time you'd allow it to spend, it does not mean it will keep trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch works in "near-real time", which means that after you index a document, it might not be available for search immediately.

You need to pass the [`refresh=true` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh) to the index action in order to make sure that the index is refreshed so you can make that new document available for search immediately.

Note, however, that if you GET the document (instead of search for it), you'll be able to retrieve the document without the need to set refresh to true.